# Can MonoTouch.Dialog be used with cascading data sources?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have the equivalent of 3 cascading data sources or drop down lists. Since all data has to be created up front will this be a good candidate for MonoTouch.Dialog as one item's data depends on the preceding value?

Example of what I'm trying to do:
I have a list of client names and each client can have a list of projects and each project can have a list of tasks.

I like the UI of tables that MT.D creates. If MT.D is not suitable for this, what would be a good approach for getting a similar UI? Would I have to create a separate UITableView and data source for each item (Client, Project, and Plan) with only one row in it?

The UI that I'm trying to replicate is having a single rounded table cell with the type on the left (e.g. Client), an accessory indicator on the right, and once a value is selected have the value on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can!**. Just have a look at [Touch.Unit](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/category/touch-unit/) [source code](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit) on github.

It shows you the assemblies (first level), then the test fixture (second level) then the test cases (third level) and, if it fails, it will show you the failure details (on a fourth level).

All this is created dynamically when the assemblies are scanned to find `[TestFixture]` attributes on the types.

Even if this does not match exactly what you're looking for you'll see that customizing [MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) is very easy. There are several questions (here on stackoverflow), samples (e.g. [TweetStation](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation)) and [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7OC5r8ZkYg) on how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response; however that's not quite what I was asking for. I'm not saying that a Client will be "page 1" and navigate to Project on "page 2" and so forth. I'm saying that I have three cells on the same page and the one physically above it will filter the available values for it.

Comment: An image is worth a 1000 words. Something like **Ringtone** from https://a248.e.akamai.net/assets.github.com/img/a8e1b2b17a72c36301194ee9c861d162702f0f3f/687474703a2f2f746972616e69612e6f72672f696d616765732f4d544469616c6f6753616d706c652e706e67 ? and when you come back from the selection *page* then you have different choices for **New Text Message**. If so it should not be an issue since each time you return to the main *page* you can recreate (or switch) the elements being used.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do - if I change the **Ringtone** then I want to have different values for **New Text Message**.
My question now is how do I change the data since I'm creating **Ringtone** and **New Text Message** cells on the Settings page before I push it on the navigation controller?

Comment: You can regenerate your `RootElement` (or parts of it) each time your *main* `DialogViewController` appear again (e.g. override `ViewWillAppear`) based on the current state of your application (i.e. if you select a *Client* then change the **global** state then you your regenerated your `RootElement`, e.g. using the `Root` property, the only add the *Project* that are related to this client).

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's exactly what I did.

Not sure if it is the best way, but I subclassed DialogViewController and RadioElement. In addition to what @poupou said, I had to pass an empty `RootElement("")` to my sub DVC to navigate to it. I also used some static fields on my DVC and my RadioElement so that I could keep track of what item was selected and then use that to filter my results using LINQ. Also the ctor for my RadioElement takes in an `NSAction` so that I can pop the controller when tapped and to store the id of the item.